# Is there a non-ArcPy way of joining a table to an existing raster attribute table using Python?

Tags: python, raster, attribute-table, attribute-joins

I have an existing raster with attribute table and would like to join a csv to it. Is there an open source way of doing so using Python libraries like rasterio, pygeoprocessing, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RIOS (http://rioshome.org), which is built on GDAL, to manipulate raster attribute tables (RAT) in Python. The below code shows and example of joining a CSV to an existing RAT, assuming a 1 to 1 match between rows:

```
import numpy
from osgeo import gdal
from rios import rat

print('Reading in Classification')
data = numpy.genfromtxt('class.csv', delimiter=',',
                        dtype=int, skip_header=1)
# Extract first column
classification = data[:,0]
print('Opening RAT')
inRatFile = 'in_rat.kea'
ratDataset = gdal.Open(inRatFile, gdal.GA_Update)

# Read in column names
colnames = rat.getColumnNames(inRatFile)

# Read in one column
# (just need to check same number as rows as classification)
testCol = rat.readColumn(ratDataset, colnames[0])

if testCol.shape[0] != classification.shape[0]:
    raise Exception("The classification file doesn't"
                    " contain the same number of rows as the RAT")

rat.writeColumn(ratDataset, 'JoinedClass', classification)
ratDataset = None
```

The columns are read as NumPy arrays so if you need to do any manipulation NumPy can be used.

Note this will read the entire column to memory, if you have a really large RAT the ratapplier function is available which will read a subset of rows at once.